# Have to rebuild usb wifi drivers on each reboot

Tags: drivers, wireless, netgear

I have the beloved and eternally loathed RTL8812 driver for my Netgear A6100 USB Wifi.

I have the zip file from Netgear on my desktop. Everything is fine, except for the fact that every time the kernel changes, I have to re "make" the file, insert a module, then make a change to some directory. This usually happens after any updates, or upgrades (ie. 14-04 to 16-04).

The first couple of "makes" is pretty long, lots of files/directories. After a few times of that, it compiles it a lot quicker.

Granted I copied/pasted everything from the readme file, so I can't say I know exactly what I'm doing. But I just want it to load the module on its own so I don't have to run these commands each time I reboot.

```
who@where:~/Desktop/rtl8812au-master$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/build 
M=/home/who/Desktop/rtl8812au-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic'
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic'
who@where:~/Desktop/rtl8812au-master$ sudo insmod 8812au.ko
who@where:~/Desktop/rtl8812au-master$ sudo cp 8812au.ko 
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
```

Thanks for reading/any help, in advance.

Comment: You can use persistence , that way you would not have to run make every time. Or you would need to remaster the ,iso. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization . Extract the .iso, run make, copy the module, repackage the iso, and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you try:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Please post any errors.

Reboot.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.